# Is "unpurposeful" a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

I know that there are different opinions about whether or not questions like "is that a word" are correct. But for now, I want to be less free in my word usage.

I did find "unpurposeful" in Wiktionary, but the Collins Online Dictionary and the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary do not have such a word.

The Merriam-Webster dictionary has the word "nonpurposeful," but, first of all, the Collins Dictionary doesn't have it, and also the word just sounds dry or legal or academic. I would really prefer to use "unpurposeful."

I also looked up antonyms of the word "purposeful" and none of them convey the meaning that I need.

What should I do in such situations? Just trust myself to use "good enough English?"

Comment: Until you tell us what meaning you need, we won't know. Similarly, we won't know what words you discarded and why until  you tell us. **Please edit your post to include this missing information.** This will automatically nominate your question for reopening.

Comment: Do you mean *not on purpose*? Or *not having purpose*?

Comment: It also depends what you're writing. Some places frown on words that aren't in their dictionary, but if it's personal writing you have wider scope.

Comment: It is generally permissible to add prefixes/suffixes that are in dictionaries to words that are in dictionaries, even if the resulting constructions are not themselves in any dictionary. The absence of such a construction from dictionaries is, however, an indication that it is uncommon, so a writer who is considering using it has to exercise judgement as to whether the aptness of the construction for the writer's purpose outweighs the risk of its being perceived as awkward.